# If jQuery is that great, why then browser vendors do not will to build it in?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why web browsers don't have jQuery built in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279091/why-web-browsers-dont-have-jquery-built-in)

If jQuery is that great, why then browser vendors do not will to build it in?

Comment: Hmm, joined today, no reputation, mimics name of very popular user, asks jQuery not-a-real-question question... Another one of them bored 4channers or whatever they are.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery is a javascript library. It's not a standard. Any browser supporting javascript will automatically support JQuery.

ECMAScript is a standard and Javascript is one of it's dialects.

JQuery is not the only way to use Javascript. JQuery is a js library that makes DOM manipulation easier and much more. Infact, it's not as close to Native javascript when it comes to usage syntax when compared to libraries like Mootools, Prototype, etc which make heavier use of prototypal OO in javascript to make javascript easier and cross browser compatible .