# why browsers don't put important javascript library like jquery or extjs in their package?

Tags: javascript, browser

why web browsers don't put important javascript library like jquery or extjs in their package?
with this work sites loading time be low.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why web browsers don't have jQuery built in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279091/1048572) and [Why is jQuery not integrated within the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8287607/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [CDN for jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery). Using it assures, jQuery will be in browser cache even if someone visits certain site first time.

Answer (score 0):

How do you propose that a browser differentiate between a reference to `/libs/jQuery.js` and one to `/libs/SomeApplication/someFeature/jQuery.js` ?

Especially if

- the first one is an old version where you integrated one or two bugfixes
- and the other one just the compatibility layer for jQuery in SomeApplication (so not even anything related to jQuery own source code)