# Why is jQuery not integrated within the browser

Tags: jquery, browser

Why isn't jQuery intergrated into browsers, so there would be no need to have to reference it on your site, and instead, the browser just notices the jQuery used, and everything works fine.

Even though referencing jQuery isn't that difficult, it stil would be a very cool feature to have.
Thanks.

Comment: i was thinking the same few days a go... it's stupid every developer to have to include and make user to download in EACH site..

Comment: So what about the 99.9% of the world who obtained a browser before your idea?

Comment: Besides, by referencing the libraries (jquery and such) from CDNs (like google), people genrally have a cached version locally, so it does not even request the file anymore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why web browsers don't have jQuery built in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279091/1048572)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

THE main advantage of having jQuery in an external script is that you can obtain a new feature in a new version of jQuery and (assuming jQuery did proper cross-browser support), you can automatically have that feature available in all the browsers your viewers use.  You can code your site to use that new jQuery feature and know that it will work in all browsers in common use.

If jQuery functionality was built into the browser, you'd be stuck with a least common denominator approach.  You could rely on no more features than were in the most backward browser or oldest browser that you wanted to be compatible with.  When a new feature was introduced, you'd have to wait nearly a decade for all older browsers that don't support that new feature to drop out of common use before you could be sure it was safe to use.  Or, you'd have to build your own cross-browser support for it, thus creating a new jQuery-like cross-browser library and the circle would start over again.

With jQuery, you just include the newest version of the library in your site and you can automatically use that new feature in all common browsers.

As for efficiency, you aren't losing much by including jQuery as an external file is it is done properly.  If you use one of the more common CDNs (like Google) to link to jQuery, then jQuery is probably already in the browser cache and it's loaded from local hard disk rather than downloaded each time it's needed.  Yes, it could be optimized further if it was built in, but then you lose all those benefits talked about earlier which negates the whole reason for having it in the first place.

Also, it's not like the built-in capabilities aren't moving forward every year.  They are.  It's called the standards movement.  The issue is that it moves very slowly.  Look at CSS3 transitions.  We have CSS3 transition support today in all popular versions of Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari, but not in any version of IE yet.  So, since we're still a long ways from all popular use of IE7, IE8 and IE9 disappearing, we're a long ways from being able to just "use" CSS3 and expect the browser to support it.  An animation library is still needed.  Even if IE10 shipped tomorrow and automatically supported all of CSS3 transitions, we'd still be many years away from when all older versions of IE stopped being used on the web.

Comment: Wow.. Perfect explanation

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to avoid this by keeping every present version in the browser? EX site adds a tag for `jquery 1.9.1`, Browser detects that and instead of issuing a request to the site, it plugs in it's own `jquery 1.9.1`. On another site it sees a tag for `jquery 7.4` and since it doesn't have that file, requests it from the server?

Comment: The browser already basically does that via caching if you use jQuery from a CDN.

Comment: but we can put check in our code that, if the browser version exists / matches / and compatible or ok to use then use it from browser otherwise request from web server

Comment: @NitinDhomse - Browser version checking is not recommended.  You can do "browser feature detection".  If you google that, you will see how it works.  But, doing what you suggested means you have two implementations, one that uses native browser APIs and one that uses jQuery.  There are times when you might do that for a few special features, but you certainly don't want your whole UI manipulation to be that way (two separate implementations).

Comment: Yes, actually I&#39;m already using some web standard features like custom elements, shadow DOM etc, I&#39;m checking like if browser is not supporting customElements then I'm requesting js for polyfill support dynamically

Comment: @NitinDhomse - That technique works well for polyfills (since you can still have only one version of your code) as long as you're using feature detection, not browser version number.

Comment: I am not saying about browser version, there might be my mistake in typing, I'm mean to say is if browsers start supporting js like jquery and bootstrap natively, they can maintain the library version and provide api to developer to simply check availability and version, so developers will just check the condition like compatibility and support and perform accordingly, there can be several ways to implement it more better way

Comment: There are several js and CSS popular, open source and secure library those are used by millions of sites and this seems downloading overhead atleast first time even if browser can cache it

Comment: The browser can also provide the way to auto upgrade libraries to stable version and any way we will have a check as a developer or its our choice use native one or download from server to ensure that site will not break UI or functionality

Answer (score 5):

Because then different browsers would have different incompatible versions.

Any native implementation is guaranteed to have some subtle difference from the real thing; eventually, we would need a cross-browser *jQuery* wrapper, and the cycle would repeat.

It would also make updates much more complicated.

It would also break other libraries that define `$` functions (eg, Prototype).

Comment: For this to happen, jQuery would have to become a specification or standard, which makes no sense.  Anything that adds extra features to a language for a specific purpose should be a framework.

Answer (score 2):

Fast forward to 2018: web browsers get updated pretty much on a monthly basis (except for Edge/IE which seem to be semi-annually which is still good).  So the point about keeping up with the latest version is meh, considering jQuery has matured so much that people seldom use the latest/newest features right away, nor are there any serious bugs.

In an era of high speed Internet and reduced size jQuery 3, plus browser caching and CDNs, downloading is not the argument here either.

The main point people overlook is indeed the performance boost.  Parsing/loading jQuery with EVERY... SINGLE... PAGE... is just not smart.  Imagine how much easier it will be on lower-end mobile devices not having to parse it with every page load, etc.  A native browser codebase implementation for jQuery's ***syntactic style*** to utilize JavaScript/ECMAScript is the goal -- and in my books, it's inevitable.  A nice catalyst would be someone at Mozilla/Chromium community who has great power/influence + OOTB thinking + courage, (à la Steve Jobs), to make this a reality.

Answer (score 1):

First, there's nothing special about JQuery - it's just a more human-friendly way to code JavaScript. It takes care of more cross-browser quirks, etc. so the developer doesn't have to think about it so much.

That being said, JQuery follows ECMAScript standards, and so do browsers. IE is a stubborn one because it uses proprietary JScript not JavaScript.

The browser shouldn't handle that burdon. Do you really want to go back to the days of bloated browsers that hog 500+mb of ram and take 10 seconds to open?

On a final note, if Mozilla and Webkit just started including JQuery, it would probably piss off a lot of talented JavaScript devs who use Mootools, YUI, Dojo, etc.

Answer (score 1):

All JavaScript libraries should be integrated into a browser, which therefore uses a global storage for them (like Google, for example) so that when one library is updated, it will also be updated on that one storage center. That would be one way how, whatever the browser version, libraries won't be outdated. As for the dollar mark, I figure some function should be created by a browser like ..

```
 use_library( 'jquery' ){
     // my jquery code
 }

 use_library( 'prototype' ){
     // my prototy[e code
 }
```

However, since integrating JavaScript libraries will only be effective when the browser won't load it via internet on each request, rather only on a library update and then only once, too, it needs to have some sort of a "cool" system that checks for a new library once a day or so, making as little request as possible.

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one there are several versions of jquery, some plugins aren't compatible with newer versions, also if, lets say firefox, DID implement this, they would have to download jquery each time there's an update, there's no guarantee that chrome and other browsers would follow up on this, for example internet explorer that doesnt seem to like anything new, so you would still have to reference it for the browsers that does NOT support it.

Final not from here is, even though browsers would start to implement it, I wouldn't rely on that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to point out that a similar question has been asked on Webmasters Stack Exchange and you can find some other good answers there:

- [Why don't browsers have jQuery installed?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84683/why-dont-browsers-have-jquery-installed)